# Objects in arrays are not getting garbage collected

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I was testing a class that uses weak references to ensure that objects were able to be garbage collected and I found that objects in a List<> were never collected even if the list is no longer referenced. This is also the case with a simple array. The following code snippet shows a simple test that fails.

```
class TestDestructor
{
    public static bool DestructorCalled;

    ~TestDestructor()
    {
        DestructorCalled = true;
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestGarbageCollection()
{
    TestDestructor testDestructor = new TestDestructor();

    var array = new object[] { testDestructor };
    array = null;

    testDestructor = null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    Assert.IsTrue(TestDestructor.DestructorCalled);
}
```

Leaving out the initialisation of the array causes the test to pass.

Why is the object in the array not getting garbage collected?

Comment: Just a guess, but is array "really" created? Maybe it's optimized away? Can you do something with the object before you destroy it to be sure?

Comment: You should also try putting a Console.WriteLine inside the destructor.

Comment: Is this to do with generations?  On the garbage collection testDestructor still exists as an elemnet of the array (even if the array is dereferenced?) and so is not collected this cycle.  What happens if you collect twice?

Comment: What Jon Skeet about the need for `volatile` here is true, this looks like a `Debug` vs `Release` issue to me.

Comment: Silly thing is if I run this in LinqPad (replacing the assert with `TestDestructor.DestructorCalled.Dump()`) I get True!

Comment: @BobVale: As the array isn't a GC root, it won't prevent the object from being garbage collected.

Comment: @Jon: From briefly inspecting the IL, in *release* mode, it looks like the C# compiler elides the array allocation entirely.

Comment: @Ani: Indeed - interesting. I get the same results either way, mind you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another edit: result will be always false if the array is defined in the Main()-Method-Scope, but will be true if defined in the Class-Test-Scope. Maybe thats not a bad thing.

```
class TestDestructor
{
    public TestDestructor()
    {
        testList = new List<string>();
    }

    public static volatile bool DestructorCalled;

    ~TestDestructor()
    {
        DestructorCalled = true;
    }

    public string xy = "test";

    public List<string> testList;

}

class Test
{
    private static object[] myArray;

    static void Main()
    {
        NewMethod();            
        myArray = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(TestDestructor.DestructorCalled);
        Console.In.ReadToEnd();
    }

    private static void NewMethod()
    {
        TestDestructor testDestructor = new TestDestructor() { xy = "foo" };
        testDestructor.testList.Add("bar");
        myArray = new object[] { testDestructor };
        Console.WriteLine(myArray.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is strange, especially considering Jon Skeet's answer, since the non-volatile optimization bugs occur in Release mode.

Comment: Debug mode holds the variables and objects longer (till the end of the method) so they can be inspected with the debugger.

Comment: If i run Jon Skeet´s program it fails in Debug, and succeeds in Release. VS 2010 again.

Comment: Indeed strange but true. And so this leads to the question - How do I get the test to pass in debug mode, since that's how we normally run our tests?

Comment: It returns true for me in release mode. Are you sure you didn't mix up release and debug (rebuilding the project etc.)?

Comment: Getting even stranger... For me its false now, no matter what configuration.

Comment: My updated answers returns true. But now im not sure if this clarifies everything. It still returns false if theres a reference from the Main()-Method to the array or the TestDestructor-instance, even if "nullified".

Comment: Well the array is out of scope now so this is not surprising.

Comment: Yes... thats kindof what i meant in my last comment.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Okay, I'm making some progress on this. There are three binary switches potentialy involved (at least):

- Whether the code is optimized; i.e. the `/o+` or `/o-` flag on the command line. This seems to make no difference.
- Whether the code is run *in* the debugger or not. This seems to make no difference.
- The level of debug information generated, i.e. the `/debug+`, `/debug-` or `/debug:full` or `/debug:pdbonly` command line flag. Only `/debug+` or `/debug:full` causes it to fail.

Additionally:

- If you separate the `Main` code from the `TestDestructor` code, you can tell that it's the compilation mode of the `Main` code which makes the difference
- As far as I can tell, the IL generated for `/debug:pdbonly` is the same as for `/debug:full` *within the method itself* so it may be a manifest issue...

EDIT: Okay, this is now really weird. If I disassemble the "broken" version and then reassemble it, it works:

```
ildasm /out:broken.il Program.exe
ilasm broken.il
```

ilasm has three different debug settings: `/DEBUG`, `/DEBUG=OPT`, and `/DEBUG=IMPL`. Using either of the first two, it fails - using the last, it works. The last is described as enabling JIT optimization, so presumably that's what's making a difference here... although to my mind it *should* still be able to collect the object either way.

---

It's possible that this is due to the memory model in terms of `DestructorCalled`. It's not volatile, so there's no guarantee that the write from the finalizer thread is "seen" by your test thread.

Finalizers certainly *are* called in this scenario. After making the variable volatile, this standalone equivalent example (which is just simpler for me to run) certainly prints True for me. That's not proof, of course: without `volatile` the code isn't guaranteed to fail; it's just not guaranteed to work. Can you get your test to fail *after* making it a volatile variable?

```
using System;

class TestDestructor
{
    public static volatile bool DestructorCalled;

    ~TestDestructor()
    {
        DestructorCalled = true;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestDestructor testDestructor = new TestDestructor();

        var array = new object[] { testDestructor };
        array = null;

        testDestructor = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(TestDestructor.DestructorCalled);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I've just seen this fail when built with Visual Studio, but it was fine from the command line. Looking into the IL now...

Comment: I think SO should force a comment when downvoting.

Comment: It prints true in release mode even if there is no volatile so it seems like your theory is wrong. (BTW I wasn't the one who downvoted :) )

Comment: @Stilgar: It *might* print True - but it's not guaranteed to. That's the point - that's why I said "there's no guarantee". Will edit to clarify a bit.

Comment: Adding volatile has no effect for me. It still fails in debug mode and passes in release.

Comment: @PaulHaley: Okay, thanks for confirming. What does the standalone app in my answer do for you? Oh, and which version of .NET are you using, and on what architecture? Any funny GC switches (parallel GC etc)?

Comment: Why are we assuming that it is not simply the way the GC acts in debug mode vs release mode?

Comment: @Stilgar: Because arrays which are eligible for garbage collection do *not* prevent objects from being garbage collected. This *should* still pass in a debug build.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I get the same result when I run your stand alone app. I'm using .NET 4 and VS2010. I haven't changed any GC switches.

Comment: @PaulHaley: So my app prints False for you when launched in a debug build? Even when you're not using the debugger? Which CPU architecture?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes. It's the same for x86 and Any CPU. I'm running on 32-bit Windows XP.

Comment: @JonSkeet it may prevent it in debug mode. BTW the app always prints false in debug mode and true in release mode for me regardless of the volatile. Testing in x86 mode without debugger.

Comment: @Stilgar: It shouldn't though - that's my point. There should be nothing keeping it alive. I've edited my post with the results of some more investigations.

Comment: I have found that moving the construction and nullifying code into a separate method causes the test to pass.

Comment: @PaulHaley: Right. I have a theory... editing now. EDIT: Scratch that. Turned out not to be right when I worked out a test for it :(

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Ani in the comments the whole Array is optimized away in release mode so we should change the code to look like this:

```
class TestDestructor
{
    public static bool DestructorCalled;
    ~TestDestructor()
    {
        DestructorCalled = true;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TestDestructor testDestructor = new TestDestructor();

        var array = new object[] { testDestructor };
        Console.WriteLine(array[0].ToString());
        array = null;

        testDestructor = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine(TestDestructor.DestructorCalled);
    }
}
```

For me it works (without volatile) and prints True always. Can anyone confirm that the finalizer is not called in release mode because otherwise we can assume it is related to debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken it's because the object is essentially copied and separate from it's initial creation when loaded into the array. Then when you destroy the array and original object, the object copied to the array still exists.

Garbage Collection should do it's job eventually, but I get that you're trying to force it to clear resources. What I would try is to clear the array first (removing the object) before destroying it, and see if it gets rid of everything.

Comment: Notice that the assert is for the static member, so any one of the two garbage collections should trigger it. The code above should work.

Answer (score 0):

That's what [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s71x931.aspx) says:

> Implementing Finalize methods or destructors can have a negative impact on performance and you should avoid using them unnecessarily. Reclaiming the memory used by objects with Finalize methods requires at least two garbage collections. [...] A future garbage collection will determine that the finalized objects are truly garbage because they are no longer pointed to by entries in the list of objects marked as ready for finalization. In this future garbage collection, the objects' memory is actually reclaimed.

Try to use a mechanism of disposing instead of finalizing to see what will happen

Comment: it is relevant because assuming that it needs a couple of GCs to run the finalizers the code should call GC.Collect twice. My experiments show that this does not help.