# C#: Re-new ing arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection

Say I have the following class that simply allocates an array:

```
public class ArrayAllocator
{
    private int[] _arr;

    public int [] Allocate(uint size)
    {
        _arr = new int[size];
        return _arr;
    }
}
```

Which I then use like this:

```
ArrayAllocator allocator = new ArrayAllocator();
int [] result;
result = allocator.Allocate(10); // create space for 10 ints
result = allocator.Allocate(20); // create space for 20 ints, using the same pointer
```

Does the GC know that I have finished with the initial 10 ints when I make the next allocation using the same pointer `_arr` and free the memory when it runs?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104352/force-garbage-collection-of-arrays-c-sharp


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200112/c-sharp-arrays-compared-to-c-arrays-and-the-garbage-collector


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091457/objects-in-arrays-are-not-getting-garbage-collected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `Allocate` function the `_arr` is pointing to new location in memory,  if there is no live instance which is pointing to your earlier `_arr` (memory pointer) then that memory is applicable for GC'ed as no more live references can be found pointing to old memory.

Remember: GC marks the objects applicable for Garbage Collection when no more live references do exist in the program by which that object can be reached.

**EDIT** So your question

> Does the GC know that I have finished with the initial 10 ints when I make the next allocation using the same pointer `_arr` and free the memory when it runs?

has a simple answer, *YES* it knows that memory pointed by old array, has no more live references pointing to it and it will be marked as Garbage and shortly memory will be recollected.

Comment: I've edited the code snipped above but I think your answer still applies.